# Class constructor "eating" up values

Tags: c++, class, random, simulation

So I'm trying to run this sim program for a class that makes us build  a Bet class using sets.

Here's the class definition:

```
class Bet2{
private:
    set<int> mainNumbers;
    set<int> luckyNumbers;
public:
    Bet2();
    void show() const;
    set<int> getMainNumbers();
    set<int> getLuckyNumbers();
};
```

So I decided to use the random lib, since the rand() function that they gave us in class spat out the same values when creating a bunch of Bet2 objects at once, for the sim.

However, for some reason, it's not spitting out the number of values it's supposed to. Sometimes it spits out 4 main numbers (instead of 5), or just 1 lucky number (instead of 2)

Here's the code for the constructor:

```
Bet2::Bet2() {
    random_device rd;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> main(1, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        mainNumbers.insert(main(rd));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> star(1, 12);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        luckyNumbers.insert(star(rd));
}
```

I ran a few tests using the uniform_int_distribution and the random_device, in the main fucntion, and it ran without any problem. For some reason it eats up values when i initialize a Bet2 vector for my sim:

```
Main Numbers: 11 23 27 32 36
Star Numbers: 3 11
Main Numbers: 4 18 22 27 28
Star Numbers: 9 11
Main Numbers: 3 5 25 43      <-
Star Numbers: 1              <-
Main Numbers: 40 42 43 46 50
Star Numbers: 2 7
Main Numbers: 7 10 14 27 45
Star Numbers: 9 10
Main Numbers: 11 15 21 24 35
Star Numbers: 1 11
Main Numbers: 3 25 29 45 50
Star Numbers: 3 7
Main Numbers: 11 15 23 25 37
Star Numbers: 1 6
Main Numbers: 7 8 26 31 43
Star Numbers: 6 9
Main Numbers: 15 27 36 38 39
Star Numbers: 2 8
```

Tried to figure out of uniform_int_distribution can not generate a value, but didnt't find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you used sets. Do you know how sets work? Especially, do you know what happens when you insert the same value twice? You got exactly what you asked for, a collection of unique values ;)

Comment: Are you aware that a `std::set` filters out duplicates? (That's on use case for what a `std::set` is made for.) If you don't like this, use a `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) can store only up to 1 copy of a given value.

The lack of numbers should be because the random numbers happened to become the same as the numbers that were previously seen.

If you want to store multiples of the same value, you should use [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) instead.

If you want to generate a unique set of defined number of values, it may be better to first generate a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of candidate values, and then use [`std::sample()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) for that.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick reply!
In this case its a lottery-type bet, so multiset doesn't apply. Fixed it using a while(set1.size() < x).
Thanks for your answer tho! really shed some light :) cheers!